# Angular 2 @ContentChildren vs @ViewChildren vs @Query

Tags: angular

I know that `@ContentChildren` selects elements from a `<ng-content>` element and `@ViewChildren` from 'outside' of `<ng-content>` element, e.g. what's inside of you HTML template.

How is `@Query` different from them and why it can be used in a constructor and the two above cannot?

*(What is better to use?)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Query` and `@ViewQuery` are deprecated and replaced by `@ContentChildren` and `@ViewChildren`

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata.dart#L162
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata.dart#L137

Comment: I can't find where're `@Query` and `@ViewQuery` marked as deprecated. Am I looking at the right place? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewQuery-var.html

Comment: Links are not working @Gunter,,